# How do you wait for API calls in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, google-api

I expect this is a noob question. The following works fine:

```
let maps = require('@google/maps').createClient({ key: '*********' });

exports.getTimeZone = (req, res, next) => {
    maps.geocode({
        address: address
    }, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        res.json(response);
    });
}
```

But once I tried to turn it into a simple function it seems to not wait for the response:

```
function callGoogleGeocode(address) {
    maps.geocode({
        address: address
    }, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return err;
        }
        return res;
    });
}
```

Is there a way to wait for the response without calling a new function from within the call?

EDIT: What you marked me as a duplicate with is for JQuery, which is not what I'm using.

Comment: be aware that 'duplicate' means 'this question is answered here' ... and it is, in more ways than one. Read the answers and pick your choice.

Comment: @Alex please take more than one second to ***read the answers*** on that post. Of course it's answered, and in javascript, countless times.